# using a template class without a template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project with a template class that takes the templated value in the constructor like this:

```
template< typename A >
struct Foo
{
    const A& a_;
    Foo( const A& a ) : a_( a ) { };
};
```

Therefore, I have to construct this class like this:

```
int myval = 0;
Foo< int > foo( myval );
```

It seems redundant to have to specify `int` as a template parameter when it's already specified in the constructor. I'd like some way to use it like this:

```
Foo foo( myval );
```

As is, I get the compiler error:

```
error C2955: 'Foo' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: I believe this is impossible. I spent a day on this and found several sources saying it wasn't standard, and I couldnt get msvc or g++ happy with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you name the type at all, it has to be the complete type (i.e., `Foo<int>` and not just `Foo`).

A class can have multiple constructors or may have no constructors that have a parameter of the class template's type parameter, so there's no way to make this work for all class templates (in my opinion it would be confusing to have this work sometimes but not all the time).

If you are okay not naming the type at all, you can write a `MakeFoo<T>()` function template that constructs a `Foo<T>` and use function template argument deduction:

```
template <typename A>
Foo<A> MakeFoo(const A& a) { return Foo<A>(a); }
```

This pattern is commonly used in C++ (see, for example, `make_shared`).

If you want to store the returned object in a variable, though, that variable still needs to have a type.  If you are able to move to a compiler that supports C++0x's `auto` (like Visual C++ 2010), then you can use that.  Otherwise, you can use a third-party solution like [`BOOST_AUTO`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/typeof/refe.html) or write your own (though that would likely be quite a lot of work (-: ).

With `auto`, your code would look like:

```
auto foo(MakeFoo(myval));
```

Answer (score 7):

C++17 *fixed* this issue, introducing [template argument deduction for constructors](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r1.html).

Citing [Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2016/06/30/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-oulu/):

> [...] you can write just `pair p(2, 4.5);` instead of `pair<int,double> p(2, 4.5);` or `auto p = make_pair(2, 4.5);`. This is pretty sweet, including that it obsoletes many “make” helpers.

Answer (score 4):

Type deduction happens only with *function* template argument, not with *class* template argument.

In C++0x, you can do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
Foo<T> CreateFoo(const T & a)
{
    return Foo<T>(a);
}

auto foo = CreateFoo(myval); //No need to write CreateFoo<int>(myval);
```