# Initiating templated class without template variable

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using a template class without a template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388844/using-a-template-class-without-a-template-argument)

If I have a templated function, I don't need to instantiate it, since it can be inferred from the arguments, like so:

```
template<typename T> void MyFunc(T arg);

int x;    
MyFunc(x);
```

Is this true for any scenario where the compiler can guess the template parameters? Specifically, I am thinking of this:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(T) { }
};

int x;
MyClass<int> c1(x); // regular style
MyClass c2(x); // is this allowed?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

The compiler doesn't deduce types for class template parameters, but does allow defaults, so if you're using `int` quite a bit for this template, you could do:

```
template <typename T=int>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(T) {}
};

int x;
MyClass<> c2(x);
```

Note that this only works for one particular type per template though. It's not choosing the type based on the type of parameter you supply, just using the default you've specified for the template, is you didn't specify a type but passed (say) a `double`, the template above would still instantiate over `int`, not `double`.

Since the compiler can/will deduce template parameters for function templates, you can also create a small template function and use `auto`:

```
template <class T>
MyClass<T> make_MyClass(T const &v) {
   return MyClass<T>(v);
}

int x;

auto c2 = make_MyClass(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't allowed, as the compiler can only deduce the types during template function invocation.

That said, the common solution is a helper function.

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(T) { }
};

template<typename T>
MyClass<T> makeMyClass(T x)
{
  return MyClass<T>(x);
}
```

Comment: @JerryCoffin: You're right, I did.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't allowed; template parameters deduction works only for template functions, template classes don't deduct template parameters from the parameters given to the constructor.